# CM Source takes long time to download.Is there any way to reduce it?

Tags: android, git, android-source, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to build custom rom for my device from CM source.I'm following this guide to build:

https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_quark

I'm using this command to sync the source.

```
repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.1
```

During download i can see other branches like 7,8,9,10,11,12.Is there any way to download only current branch (12.1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `repo sync` command is same as `git clone` when used without any flags, that means you are simply downloading all the branches from all the repositories defined in the manifest file (visit [this](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git) and see the `default.xml` file).

To download only the current branch that is `cm-12.1`, use the `-c` flag while using the `repo sync` command. Note that the Android source is made from many projects and is a huge download when you are syncing for the first time.

So your commands should be:

1. `repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.1`
2. `repo sync -c`

For a better understanding of how `repo` tool works just read this [article](http://xda-university.com/as-a-developer/repo-tips-tricks).

I hope this helps.